# Spring - List references a DOA method to get its values

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am brand new to spring and I am trying to write my first spring application.

I have set up a DOA class that accesses the DB and pulls a list of values. I would like to reference those values in a bean definition.

For Example:
I have DAO class called "JdbcDataDAO" that contains a method getValues() - I would like to reference the values in a standalone list in my bean definitions

Here is what I have:

```
<bean id="dataDAO" class="dao.impl.JdbcDataDAO">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<util:list id="myList" list-class="java.util.List">
  <value>#{dataDAO.values}</value>
</util:list>
```

But when I retrieve the bean "myList", it contains "#{dataDAO.values}" and not the values

Any help would be appreciated - Thanks

Comment: I dont want to put a list in a list. I want to create a singleton list of values that is drawn from the db, instead of hardcoding the values in the file. I then want to give that list an ID, so I can reference it in other beans

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if you can do this with SpEL. And it doesn't look good anyway - you are mixing infrastructure/configuration with business logic.

You can have a factory-bean or a `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` methods where you can inject the DAO and programatically populate the list.

You can also have a `BeanPostProcessor` that takes all `List` beans an fills them with whatever you want.